# why this code can't open the file for read data

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem in my code.
Why can not this code open the file?
Thanks

```
ofstream out("a.text");
while (i != 6)
{
    out << b[i] << ' ' ;
    i++ ;
}
out.close();
i = 0 ;
for ( i ; i < 6 ; i++)
{
    b[i] = 0 ;
}
ifstream in("a.txt"); // problem in this line
if(!in)
{
    cout << "error" ;
    cin.get();
    exit(0);
}
```

export from this code :
error

Comment: Just a guess, but does the file `"a.txt"` exist?  (You wrote to `"a.text"`, not `"a.txt"`.)

Answer (score 6):

you are doing output into file named `a.text` and then you try to open `a.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You write to `a.text` and read from `a.txt`:

```
ofstream out("a.text");
...
ifstream in("a.txt");
```